# Calculating ratio value within a line which contain binary numbers "0" & "1"

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a data file which contain more than 2000 lines and 45001 columns.

The first column is actually a "string" which explains the data type.

Start from column #2, up to column #45001, the data is reprsented as

> "1"

or

> "0"

For example, the pattern of data in a line is

> (0 0 0 `1 1` 0 `1 1 1` 0  `1 1 1 1` 0 0 0 `1` 0 0 `1 1 1` 0 0)

The total number of data is 25. Within this data line, there are 5 sub-groups which are made by only the number "1"s e.g. (`11` `111` `1111` `1` `111` ). The "0"s in between the subgroups are assumed as "delimiter". The total of all "1"s is = 13.

I would like to calculate the ratio of

> (total of all "1"s / total of number of sub-groups made only by "1"s)

That is

> (13/5).

I tried with this code for calculating the total of all "1"s ;

```
awk -F '0' '{print NF}' < inputfile.in
```

This gives value 13.

But I donn't know how to go further from here to calcuate the ratio that I want.
I don't know how to find the number of sub-groups within each line beacuse the number of occurances of "1"s and "0"s are random.

Wish to get some kind help to sort this problem.

Appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: post the exact input . is there any spaces before and after ti digits?

Comment: This is the sample data [BMR_10@O24-BMR_6@O13-H13 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1]. The first column is a string and the rest are the data from one row only. I can not show the actual file because the size is about 5MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me from the description what the format of the input file is.  Assume the input looks like:

```
$ cat file
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
```

To count up the number of ones and the number of groups of ones and take their ratio:

```
$ awk '{f=0;s1=0;s2=0;for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){s1+=$i;if ($i && !f)s2++;f=$i}; print s1/s2}' file
2.6
```

#### Update: Handling all zeros

Suppose one of the lines in the file has all zeros:

```
$ cat file
0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

For the second line, both sums are zero which would lead to a divide by zero error.  We can avoid that by adding an `if` statement which will print the ratio if one exists or `0/0` is it doesn't:

```
if (s2>0)print s1/s2; else print s1"/"s2
```

The complete code is now:

```
$ awk '{f=0;s1=0;s2=0;for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){s1+=$i;if ($i && !f)s2++;f=$i}; if (s2>0)print s1/s2; else print s1"/"s2}' file
2.6
0/0
```

#### How it works

The code uses three variables.  `f` is a flag which is true (1) if we are currently in a group of ones and is false (0) otherwise.  `s1` is the the number of ones on the line.  `s2` is the number of groups of ones on the line.

- `f=0;s1=0;s2=0`

  At the beginning of each line, we initialize the variables.
- `for (i=2;i<=NF;i++){s1+=$i;if ($i && !f)s2++;f=$i}`

  We loop over each field on the line starting with field 2.  If the field contains a 1, we increment counter `s1`.  If the field is 1 and is the start of a new group, we increment `s2`.
- `if (s2>0)print s1/s2; else print s1"/"s2}`

  If we encountered at least one one, we print the ratio `s1/s2`.  Otherwise, we print `0/0`.

Comment: But sir, there are lines where the data contains line with  all zero, like (0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0). So when I try, I get error saying ([vijay@glycogpu process-rawData]$ ./find-sum-and-ratio.sh 
947 17 55.7059
awk: (FILENAME=outPut3.dat FNR=2) fatal: division by zero attempted
). Could this possibly overcome?

Comment: @Vijay OK.  The updated answer has code to handle that.

Comment: This does not give correct data if you add column number `1` with the data information. OP: `Start from column #2, up to column #45001, the data is reprsented as 0 or 1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` that does what you need:

```
cat file
data 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
data 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
data 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
data 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
BMR_10@O24-BMR_6@O13-H13 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
data 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

```
awk '{$1="";$0="0 "$0" 0";t=split($0,b,"1")-1;gsub(/ +/,"");n=split($0,a,"[^1]+")-2;print (n?t/n:0)}' t
2.6
0
25
11
5.5
3
```

Comment: This does not give correct data if  the last column contains a `1`.  Try, for example, `echo data 0 1 1 | awk -F1 '{gsub(/ +/,"");n=split($0,a,"[^1]+")-2;print (n?(NF-1)/n:"0")}'`.  The result should be 2,  The code returns 0.

Comment: @John1024 It will also fail of column `1` info column does contain  `1` as in OPs comments.  Will try to fix it.

Comment: Updated with new example data to calculate correct.